# Process hangs with commands that wait for input and RedirectStandardInput is 'true'

Tags: c#, input, process, cmd

after some problems explained in another question I went ahead writing an application that simulates a Windows command prompt. Every command is executed by a Process object that calls "CMD.exe /C [command]" and redirects its standard output/error to a Winform.

It goes well but the Form crashes when I execute certain commands, like "time" or "wmic" that ask for some user interaction (RedirectStandardInput is TRUE). How can I solve this making the cursor wait for input (like a classic prompt)?

This is the code

```
        Process cmdProcess = new Process();
        cmdProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "CMD.exe";
        cmdProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C " + command;
        cmdProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = this.workingDir;
        cmdProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        cmdProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        cmdProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        cmdProcess.StartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = Encoding.Default;
        cmdProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        cmdProcess.StartInfo.StandardErrorEncoding = Encoding.Default;
        //cmdProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

        cmdProcess.Start();
        StreamReader outputR = cmdProcess.StandardOutput;
        StreamReader errorR = cmdProcess.StandardError;
        //StreamWriter inputW = cmdProcess.StandardInput;

        string output = outputR.ReadToEnd();
        string error = errorR.ReadToEnd();

        if (output.Length > 0)
            this.textArea.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + output);
        else if (error.Length > 0)
            this.textArea.AppendErrorText(Environment.NewLine + error);
```

I commented all the parts that enable input redirect and now the output of, for example, "time" command doesn't ask any user input and returns immediately. Obviously I don't like this behaviour ;)

```
C:\Users\Alessandro\Progetti\CMDProject\CMDProject\bin\Debug>time
Ora corrente: 19:32:17,55
Immettere nuova ora:
C:\Users\Alessandro\Progetti\CMDProject\CMDProject\bin\Debug>
```

Comment: when you call /wmic are you wanting to do this sychronous or async.? check out this link it has other references on how to properly use System.Diagnostics.Process for what you are possibly trying to do.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502894/wmic-mangementclass-remotecommand-determining-when-it-is-finished-stdout

Answer (score 1):

i did something similar in the past, take a look at my code, it doesnt look like you have callbascks set up, try this, changind my commands to what you want, hope this helps: if your starting another thread make sure the first is closed, as demonstrated in my code...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;

using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Globalization;

namespace VSSWriterTest
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    public class VSSCommands
    {
        public string VSS_VSSExecutable = "vssadmin";
        public string VSS_VSSListWriters = " list writers";
    }


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //close handler
        this.FormClosing+=new FormClosingEventHandler(Form1_FormClosing);

    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    //my thread and process vars
    private Process m_Process;
    private Thread m_OutputThread;
    private Thread m_ErrorThread;
    private string m_TextToAdd;

   //basic writer command line stuff
    public class WriterStats
    {
        public string WriterName = "Writer Name";
        public string WriterTD = "Writer Id";
        public string WriterInstanceId = "Writer Instance Id";
        public string WriterState = "State";
        public string WriterLastError = "Last error";
        public string NoError = "No error";
    }



    private void StartVSSDiagnostics()
    {
        try
        {
            this.rtbVSSList.Clear();
            iErrorCount = 0;
            iWriterCount = 0;
            this.txtErrors.Clear();

            //start cmd prompt, then write command statement to console screen
            if ((StartVSSDiagnosticsThreads()))
            {
                VSSCommands ServiceCall = new VSSCommands();

                string msg = ServiceCall.VSS_VSSExecutable + ServiceCall.VSS_VSSListWriters;
                VSSStreamInput(msg);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "EVAS Backup and Restore");
        }
    }

    private void VSSStreamInput(string Text)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Text != string.Empty)
            {
                m_Process.StandardInput.WriteLine(Text);
                m_Process.StandardInput.Flush();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }

    private bool StartVSSDiagnosticsThreads()
    {

        try
        {
            //close threads if open
            CloseThreads();

            //start new cmd prompt thread
            m_Process = new Process();
            {
                m_Process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd";
                m_Process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                m_Process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                m_Process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                m_Process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                m_Process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

            }
            m_Process.Start();

            //create the call backs
            m_OutputThread = new Thread(StreamOutput);
            m_OutputThread.IsBackground = true;
            m_OutputThread.Start();
            m_ErrorThread = new Thread(StreamError);
            m_ErrorThread.IsBackground = true;
            m_ErrorThread.Start();

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    //this stream is feedback from the command prompt, its a delegate thats on a seperate thread other than this UI
    private void StreamOutput()
    {
        try
        {
            string Line = m_Process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();

            while (Line.Length >= 0)
            {
                if (Line.Length > 0)
                {
                    ConsoleMessage(ConvertFromOem(Line));
                }
                Line = m_Process.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            //ConsoleMessage(String.Format("""{0}"" Error!", m_Process.StartInfo.FileName))
        }
    }


    //convert text encoding to readable characters
    private string ConvertFromOem(string Text)
    {
        try
        {
            return Encoding.GetEncoding(CultureInfo.InstalledUICulture.TextInfo.OEMCodePage).GetString(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Text));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }

    //stream error callback
    private void StreamError()
    {
        try
        {
            string Line = m_Process.StandardError.ReadLine();

            while (Line.Length >= 0)
            {
                Line = m_Process.StandardError.ReadLine();
                if (Line.Length > 0)
                {
                    ConsoleMessage(Line, true);
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            //ConsoleMessage(String.Format("""{0}"" Error!", m_Process.StartInfo.FileName))
        }
    }

    //actual delegate that invokes the main thread
    private void ConsoleMessage(string Text, bool err = false)
    {
        try
        {
            if (err)
            {
                m_TextToAdd = "ERROR: " + Text;
            }
            else
            {
                m_TextToAdd = Text;
            }

            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)this.RaiseConsoleTextEvent);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }


    //raise  text event, new text arrived from console
    private void RaiseConsoleTextEvent()
    {
        try
        {
            VSSMessages(m_TextToAdd);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }


    //my message filter, what i want displayed on my UI, i parse microsoft logo and garbage to display results only
    private int iErrorCount = 0;
    private int iWriterCount = 0;
    private void VSSMessages(string e)
    {
        WriterStats IWriter = new WriterStats();


        if ((e.ToUpper().Contains(IWriter.WriterInstanceId.ToUpper()) | e.ToUpper().Contains(IWriter.WriterLastError.ToUpper()) |
            e.ToUpper().Contains(IWriter.WriterName.ToUpper()) | e.ToUpper().Contains(IWriter.WriterState.ToUpper()) |
            e.ToUpper().Contains(IWriter.WriterTD.ToUpper())))
        {
            if ((e.ToUpper().Contains(IWriter.WriterName.ToUpper())))
            {
                iWriterCount += 1;
                this.rtbVSSList.AppendText("Writer (" + iWriterCount.ToString() + ") " + e + Environment.NewLine);
            }
            else
            {
                this.rtbVSSList.AppendText(e + Environment.NewLine);
            }

            if ((e.ToUpper().Contains(IWriter.WriterLastError)))
            {
                if ((e.ToUpper().Contains(IWriter.NoError)))
                {
                    iErrorCount += 1;
                    this.txtErrors.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                }
            }

            this.txtErrors.Text = iErrorCount.ToString() + " Errors found in " + iWriterCount.ToString() + " system writers.";

            if ((e.ToUpper().Contains(IWriter.WriterLastError.ToUpper())))
            {
                this.rtbVSSList.AppendText(Environment.NewLine);
            }

            Application.DoEvents();

        }


    }

    //close any open threads, dont want run away threads!
    private void CloseThreads()
    {
        try
        {
            if (((m_OutputThread != null)))
            {
                if ((m_OutputThread.IsAlive))
                {
                    m_OutputThread.Abort();
                }
            }

            if (((m_ErrorThread != null)))
            {
                if ((m_ErrorThread.IsAlive))
                {
                    m_ErrorThread.Abort();
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }

    private void btnRun_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //begin
        StartVSSDiagnostics();
    }


}
```

}